# Proof that $\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+2(\ldots)}}}} = 1+\sqrt{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, radicals, nested-radicals

I saw this problem at the 2017 math counts competition and one of the kids solved it in 5 seconds. I played around with is seeing that it could be represented as infinite nested function $f(x)=\sqrt{1+2x}$ but couldn't get much further.

https://youtu.be/vFTeN17Z4rc?t=47m54s

Comment: Solve $x=\sqrt{1+2x}$.

Comment: Is there any theory about $\sqrt {a+\sqrt{b+\sqrt a\ldots}}$ numbers like of continuous fractions?

Comment: @ajotatxe [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical) there are some references

Comment: No $\cdots$ in the quantity to be computed? Currently, the LHS is approximately $2.3605\ne1+\sqrt2$.

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question? I see no problem in this one. +1 from me.

Comment: @JaideepKhare Because the question is wrongly stated (see Did's comment above).

Answer (score 1):

Your nested function should be $f(x)=\sqrt{1+2f(x)}$

So as BAI suggested, solve $y=\sqrt{1+2y}$

---

Hint: square both sides and find the positive solution to the quadratic.   (Why only the positive?)

Comment: If the number of radical goes to infinity then solution of equation $y=\sqrt{1+2y}$is the answer which is $y=1+\sqrt2$

Answer (score 1):

Note:
$$1+\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{(1+\sqrt{2})^2}=\sqrt{1+2(1+\sqrt{2})}=...$$

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{\dots}}}=x$.

Putting this from the second root in the equation, we get
   $\sqrt{1+2x}=1+\sqrt{2}$
    solving this $x=1+\sqrt{2}$.
    so $$\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{\dots}}}=1+\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: Actually, the goal is to prove that $x=1+\sqrt{2}$ so your method would rather yield $\sqrt{1+2x}=x$. Which is BAI's suggestion (explained in Graham Kemp's answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course!

Since $\sqrt{3+2\sqrt2}=1+\sqrt2,$ we obtain:
$$...=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+2(1+\sqrt2)}}}=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+2(1+\sqrt2)}}=$$
$$=\sqrt{1+2(1+\sqrt2)}=1+\sqrt2.$$
We can see it during one second.